# Access Report Show # instead of Date

Tags: ms-access

My access report is showing **#####** instead of showing the **datetime** value in the row. When I clicks on it the ##### turn outs to the actual date as if it was hidden behind it. I have tried changing the date format to `Long Date` `Medium Date` and `Short Date` in both the related table as well as in the report's **Format** properties but is it not working at all.
Why is it so?

Comment: try making the field wider. If a numerical value is wider than the control, access shows a string of #'s instead of the value

Comment: Got it but is there any other solution to this problem bcz I already have less space to accommodate all table.fields!

Comment: Check my answer: You either increase the control or decrease the font size... or convert the value you want to display into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have can be because there's no enough space in the textbox (or other control) to display the value you need.

You can solve this by either increasing the size of the control or decreasing the size of the font you are using.

An alternative can be to convert the value you want to display into a string. Since you are dealing with dates, I sugest you use the `format$()` function. For example:

```
=format$([yourDateField],'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

will return a date in the year-month-day format. Check the online help to know more about this function.

Hope this helps you

Comment: This worked for my issue which was an Access query exporting to Excel.
Thanks.